# Speed up functions using variable types but not Compile

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, code-review

I am writing a large numerical code and I have set up many functions that take several arguments as input. In the functions I am using several built in Mathematica functions, such as Sum[], Part[], ReplacePart[], Select[], FromDigits[], IntegerDigits[] and more.
I know in advance that all the input arguments are small integers (or nested lists of small integers), definitely smaller than 100.
Also, I do care about numeric performance a lot, so I want to make sure that my functions are as fast as possible. I know about Compile[], but sometimes the compiled version of my functions are outperformed by the non compiled version, and sometimes Compile[] complains about the presence of things like ReplacePart, so I never know in advance whether it is worth to rewrite my functions in a compiled version or not.

**My question:**
Is it numerically faster to specify the argument input types? If yes, how can I do that efficiently avoiding Compile[], which conflicts with ReplacePart[] and other functions? I've tried something like Typed[], but honestly I couldn't see any relevant speed up...

**Example:**
here's a decontextualized example of one function: L, f, sigma, orb are all very small integers, while state is a nested list of small integers. Can I use this information to speed this up?

```
cdg[L_, f_, \[Sigma]_, orb_, state_]:=Module[
    {binarystate, index},
    index = f*(orb-1)+\[Sigma];
    binarystate = IntegerDigits[#,2,L]&@state;
    If[binarystate[[index,1]]==0,
        binarystate = ReplacePart[binarystate,{index,1}->1];
        Return[FromDigits[#,2]&/@binarystate],
    (*else*)
        Return[0]
    ];
];
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Specifying variable types to speed up performance doesn't work/can't be done. But you can probably gain a lot simply by improving the implementation of your functions. For instance, you seem to be only checking whether the bit at position `index` is set (and setting it if not). This can be done way more quickly using bitwise operations, no need to ever convert the state to a list of digits. Same with your return statement: Why are you converting `state` to digits and then back again, rather than simply returning the appropriate part of `state`? Finally, note that `Return` is not needed here

Comment: (After the improvements outlined in the previous comment you should also be able to compile the function if you need more performance)

Comment: Thanks! I will stop trying to set the variable types and focus more on reducing the number of functions that I call in each function. Your suggestion was very helpful as I obtained a speed up of a factor 2 / 3.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a version that avoids the explicit conversion to binary digits and uses only bitwise operations:

```
ClearAll[cdg2]
cdg2[L_, f_, σ_, orb_, state_] := Module[
  {mask, index},
  index = f*(orb - 1) + σ;
  mask = 2^(L - 1);
  MapAt[BitOr[mask, #] &, state, index]
]

state = {6, 21, 5, 29, 13, 28, 26, 8, 28, 2, 9, 16, 26, 19};

Equal @@ Through[{cdg, cdg2}[8, 4, 2, 3, state]]
(* Out: True *)
```

The timing is improved roughly 4x with this version:

```
RepeatedTiming[cdg[10, 3, 2, 1, state];, 5]  (* Out: {0.0000242844, Null} *)
RepeatedTiming[cdg2[10, 3, 2, 1, state];, 5] (* Out: {6.975*10^-6, Null}  *)
```

The above version should be compilable as well (at least `MapAt` and the bitwise operations are listed in this [List of compilable functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101/27951)).

Comment: Building on @MarcoB's solution--Replacing `Module` with `With` gives another 2x speed improvement:
```cdg3[L_, f_, \[Sigma]_, orb_, state_] := With[
  {index = f*(orb - 1) + \[Sigma],
   mask = 2^(L - 1)},
  MapAt[BitOr[mask, #] &, state, index]]```

Comment: Even faster: `cdg4[L_, f_, σ_, orb_, state_] := MapAt[BitSet[#, L - 1] &, state, f*(orb - 1) + σ]` (i.e. using `BitSet` and no `With` at all)

Comment: Or a compiled version that gives a factor of 5 compared to `cdg2`: `cdg5 =
 Compile[{{L, _Integer}, {f, _Integer}, {σ, _Integer}, {orb, _Integer}, {state, _Integer, 1}}, MapAt[BitOr[#, 2^(L - 1)] &, state, f*(orb - 1) + σ], CompilationTarget -> "C"]` (without `BitSet` as that is not compilable)

Comment: Wow! thanks a lot!! I was definitely looking at the wrong thing: the variable types, but there was clearly much more that I could do changing my approach